# Check for system audio volume changes

Tags: python, audio, signals, system, daemon

I want my python app to react when the system volume changes (either by user input or by the system itself).

I know one way to do it is using the pycaw library and put the GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar function in a while True loop, but that just hogs resources.

Is there a simple way of doing this without implementing a completely separate daemon process that would check for that?